# No se puede conectar al servidor MySQL local a través del socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

> ```
> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)
> ```

Tengo error al momento de conectar MYSQL con el servidor, ya hice las previas configuraciones de apache y Mysql.   intentado hacer `-h` (nombre de usuario) `-u` (usuario) y me sale este error.

Linux-Manjaro

Comment: Y se está ejecutando el servidor? Como puedes verificar que está funcionando el servicio mysqld?

Comment: Buenas, si el servidor  esta funcionando, systemctl status httpd  y esta funcionando...

Comment: Pero httpd es el servidor web, el servidor de base de datos es `mysql`. ¿Puedes consultar los logs? ¿Ejecutar `mysqld`? ¿Conectarte por localhost  o IP?

Comment: pues compruebo, en el shell compruebo con sudo systemctl status mysqld y como resultado aparece que esta activado.

Comment: A. ¿La ruta del socket está indicada en tu archivo `my.cnf `. Algo como: `socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` B. ¿Puedes ver si MySQL está corriendo? `mysqladmin -u root -p status` C. ¿Problema de permisos? `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/` D. Si nada de esto funciona, revisa el log, quizá encuentres la causa específica del problema en él: `/var/log/mysql`

Comment: B.  Acceso denegado e dado la password y a salido esto`mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'` 
C. el archivo mysql no se en cuentra en `/var/lib/`  Y el archivo mysql no se encuentra en log tampoco.